Allure report does not display the Trend after launch
I'm having problems with the fact that I don't display Trends from previous launches. I will be glad of any help. My gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - test
  - deploy
  - notify

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
  REPORT_DIR: "public/allure-report"
  ALLURE_RESULTS: "results/allure-results"

before_script:
  - source /home/tester/distr/packet/myenv/bin/activate
  - python3 -m pip install pytest allure-pytest
  - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
  - mkdir -p public
  - if [ ! -f public/environment.properties ]; then touch public/environment.properties; fi
  - echo "OS=$(uname -a)" >> public/environment.properties

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - rm -rf ${ALLURE_RESULTS}
    - mkdir -p ${ALLURE_RESULTS}
    - if [ -d ${REPORT_DIR}/history ]; then cp -r ${REPORT_DIR}/history ${ALLURE_RESULTS}/history; else mkdir -p ${ALLURE_RESULTS}/history; fi
    - cp public/environment.properties ${ALLURE_RESULTS}/environment.properties
    - python3 -m pytest --alluredir=${ALLURE_RESULTS} tests/
  after_script:
    - mkdir -p ${REPORT_DIR}
    - allure generate ${ALLURE_RESULTS} -o ${REPORT_DIR} --clean
    - cp -r ${ALLURE_RESULTS}/history ${REPORT_DIR}/history
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ${REPORT_DIR}
      - ${ALLURE_RESULTS}

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir -p public
    - cp -r ${REPORT_DIR}/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master

I changed the folder location, but it didn't help and the Trend is still not displayed after generating the report
